# How could I use a per module bootstrap?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

I'm using Zend Framework 1.10.7 and I'm looking for a way to use a per module bootstrap to set up specific module configuration.

I thought it was as simple as extending `Zend_Appplication_Bootstrap_Bootstrap` and putting it at the root of the module directory, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: i think this article help http://blog.vandenbos.org/2009/07/07/zend-framework-module-config/

Answer (score 3):

See

- [Matthew Weier O'Phinney's Module Bootstraps in Zend Framework: Do's and Don'ts](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html) and
- [Rob Allen's Bootstrapping modules in ZF 1.8 and up](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/bootstrapping-modules-in-zf-1-8/)

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap is the class you want to extend. So say you had a module called 'Blog', you'd create a bootstrap class like this:

```
class Blog_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    // module specific bootstrap methods here
}
```

and put it at application/modules/blog/Bootstrap.php.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that every bootstrap will be runned, even you you load a controller of a specific module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Zend Framework.currently I'm using [" create modular application with zend"](http://www.amazium.com/blog/create-modular-application-with-zend) tutorial by Jeroen Keppens to add modularity to my application.But to load modular layouts I'm trying to follow Matthew Weier O'Phinney's Module Bootstraps in Zend Framework: Do's and Don'ts